# SCCM PXE not getting IP address

Tags: sccm

Our organization uses SCCM 2016 connected to two MS Server 2016-based DPs. The first works fine though the other recently (last 30 days or so) stopped communicating with the PXE. We don't know what exactly caused this (perhaps a CU update?). Essentially, when pressing F12 to start PXE, we don't get any IP address.

The process goes as follows:

```
>>Checking Media Presence......
>>Media Present.......
>>Start PXE Over IPv4 (MAC address)
```

In attempt to get it to work, I have restarted the DHCP server and set up a new DP, the problem persists.

Our servers are up-to-date with the latest Microsoft update (which at this point we would not like to revert due to security reasons). What would you guys suggest me do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So do you have multiple dhcp servers (one on each DP?)? Because by default the DPs do not have anything todo with whether you get an IP or not, it would be just the DHCPs job up until that point of your log.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have configured DHCP Options 66 and 67 on the scope where you attempt to boot to PXE.

Since it looks like you attempt to boot from UEFI, it will be better for you to setup a DHCP Policy to direct UEFI and BIOS clients to the correct file each time. [Here's a great tutorial for setting this up](https://marconuijens.com/2018/01/04/supporting-both-legacy-and-uefi-modes-in-your-sccm-environment/)